# Compilation issue using openssl library

Tags: c++, openssl

I am getting this error message when trying to compile "gloox" library on Fedora14 machine.

```
tlsopensslserver.cpp:248:8: warning: unused parameter âis_exportâ
tlsopensslserver.cpp: In member function âvirtual bool gloox::OpenSSLServer::privateInit()â:
tlsopensslserver.cpp:257:5: error: âEC_KEY_new_by_curve_nameâ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [tlsopensslserver.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Documents/RMSAgent/gloox-1.0/src'
```

Same code is sucessfully compiled on Ubuntu machine.

openssl-devel package is available on Fedora machine.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the code for tlsopensslserver.cpp from line 240 to line 260?

Comment: @ArunSaha gloox is opensource library:

Comment: Hmm... so you want the contributors to go find that file from the Internet and guess the version that is referred to here?

Comment: @ArunSaha gloox is opensource library:
Code is  default:
        
        return 0;
        break;
    }
  }

  RSA* tmp_rsa_callback( SSL* /*s*/, int is_export, int keylength )
  {
    return RSA_generate_key( keylength, RSA_F4, 0, 0 );
  }

  bool OpenSSLServer::privateInit()
  {
    SSL_CTX_set_tmp_rsa_callback( m_ctx, tmp_rsa_callback );
    SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh_callback( m_ctx, tmp_dh_callback );
    SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh( m_ctx, EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name( NID_sect163r2 ) );
    SSL_CTX_set_options( m_ctx, SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE );
    return true;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in gloox requires a version of OpenSSL which supports Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC). Fedora/Redhat ship a version of OpenSSL compiled without ECC support due to intellectual property concerns. Gloox should wrap ECC related code in

```
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_EC
// ECC related OpenSSL calls
#endif
```

using OpenSSL's preprocessor defines, or use autoconf to detect ECC support in OpenSSL and use autoconfigured conditionals to support OpenSSL with ECC disabled.

Alternatively, you can build your own OpenSSL with ECC enabled and build gloox against that.